# Reading multiple PDF files in Preview app Mac OS X Maverick

Tags: macos, pdf

I need to work on multiple PDF files and because of annotating those files, I prefer to use Preview built-in app for Mac OSX.

If I am in the middle of one PDF file say on Page 5, and I transit to some other PDF file and come  back to the previous file, then I always get the first page of that PDF.

Is there any setting which I can use so that I always get the page from where I left?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is, mine works as you seem to want it to. Maybe your `Preferences` are set differently. Here are mine.

[image]
[image]

Comment: All the settings are same except I am using "Open all files in one window". Could that be the problem.